# Como guardar un imagen ascii en una variable en java

Tags: java, ascii

Nose como hacer para que me lea incluyendo los saltos de linea para poder guardar toda la imagen ascii.

````
        InputStreamReader a = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(a);
        System.out.println("Ingrese imagen: ");
        String frase = "";
        frase = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(frase);
}```
````

Answer (score -2):

No comprendo tu interrogante, sin embargo te muestro esta estructura:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ejecutora {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        InputStreamReader a = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(a);
            System.out.println("Ingrese imagen: ");
                String nombre = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("" + nombre);
    }
    catch(IOException c) {
    System.err.println(c);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, solo has repetido el código que ya había puesto.